# How to remove Node from Treeview by giving Node Name using C#

Tags: c#

I am Adding node In My Treeview by this code

```
 trvMenu.Nodes.Clear();   
 trvMenu.Nodes.Add("TestNode");
```

and it added Successfully,

Now I want To remove It, So I am Writing This code

```
  TreeNode tn = new TreeNode("TestNode");
  this.trvMenu.Nodes.Remove(tn);
```

But its Not Working !!!

Currently I am removing It by finding index than remove by index and its work nicely,
by below code:

```
                    int foundIndex = 0;
                    int indexCount = 0;
                    foreach (TreeNode myString in trvMenu.Nodes)
                    {


                        if (myString.Text == "TestNode")
                        {
                            foundIndex = indexCount;


                        }
                        indexCount++;


                    } 
                    this.trvMenu.Nodes[foundIndex].Remove();
```

Kindly Help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a new Node which has a certain reference, that reference is different from the one you added.

You can use Linq, just write:

```
TreeNode node = this.trvMenu.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().FirstOrDefault( x => x.Name == "TestNode" )
if (node != null)
{
    this.trvMenu.Nodes.Remove(node);
}
```

Not sure if the "Name" property is correct, just change if needed.

**Edit:** In case someone asks later why exactly this happens: "Remove" only looks for the exact reference, which means you have to give it the exact object which you want to remove. For that, you first have to look up that object, and pass it to Remove.

Comment: Showing Compile time Error
" System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection does not contain contain defination for Cast  "

Comment: Did you add `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: okae, and if i am adding some child node, and want to remove it by giving its name, same as above, so in that case should i have give object of both? child node and Parent Node ??

Comment: That's not that easy to answer, but generally, you take a TreeNode value, get it's Nodes, and perform said Linq magic. If you don't know the parent node, you have to look for it first, but you might find multiple instances of TreeNode if you just look for the Name.

Answer (score 4):

It won't work because what you are trying to remove is a different object. Note you are creating a new TreeNode. To remove a node from the TreeView you have to find the appropriate object.

In winforms you can do it by searching for a Node with appropriate key. But first the Node you add to the tree has to have a name:

```
TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
tn.Name = "TestNode";
trvMenu.Nodes.Add(tn);
```

Than you can search for it in the tree and remove it

```
TreeNode[] nodes = trvMenu.Nodes.Find("TestNode", true);
if (nodes.Length > 0)
    trvMenu.Nodes.Remove(nodes[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you very Much, I got what i miss by your answer, I couldn't mark your answer as Accepted Answer , i already mark it to other.